# How to convert string to double

Tags: java, hashmap, double, type-conversion

```
  double d=0.0;
    for (String k : word.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(k + "\t" + word.get(k));           
        d+=Double.valueOf(word.get(k));
        d+=word.get(k);
        word.get(k);
    }
  System.out.println("Value\t"+d);
```

The values are in hashmap. Incompatible type error occurs in 5th line.how to correct it?

Comment: all the time it happens

Answer (score 6):

The line `d+=Double.valueOf(word.get(k));` will correctly add the `Double` value of `word.get(k)` to your `double d`, provided the `String` **is** parsable as `Double`.

The line after it, however, adds a `String` to a double, which will not compile.

The last line in your loop doesn't make any sense, you are invoking `get` without actually using the value.

Comment: in word i have value pairs like this ab  0.07890  cam  0.12435

Comment: @user3387277 these values should be ok. If you don't bump into a `NumberFormatException` you're essentially all right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Double.parseDouble()`

Eg:

```
String str="2.25";
double d=Double.parseDouble(str);
System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert String value to Double like this--

```
double latitu=Double.parseDouble("21.2186653");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is in  5th line that's because you are trying to add whatever you have in the set word with double d. Java do not know what you have in the set word so you can type cast it if the word is a set of double. Otherwise you have to parse the double from what "word.get(k)" returns.

try d+=(double) word.get(k), if word is a set of double
or d+=double.valueOf(word.get(k)). if you have string in the set word.

Answer (score 0):

In your 5th line of sample code, you are trying to add a string value with a double. that's why you are getting error

use

```
d += Double.parseDouble(word.get(k));
```

rather than

```
d+=word.get(k)
```